# PlayFramework 2.x and playorm ClassNotFoundException: play.Plugin

Tags: playorm

I tried to connect to the cassandra by PlayFramework 2.x, but I got common exception ClassNotFoundException: play.Plugin. I have done all what is on wiki page https://github.com/deanhiller/playorm/wiki/PlayFramework-2.x-support. Here is my maven (I use playorm.jar from mvn repository) project http://code.google.com/p/cassandranosql-firebrandocm-playorm/source/browse/trunk/, as you can see, there is a test class UserPlayormDaoImplTest, in which is called NoSql.em(); that throws ClassNotFoundException. I added plugin2.1.jar to the classpath, however, it can't find the class. I don't know what could be wrong. Thanks for help.

Stacktrace:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: play/Plugin
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
at com.alvazan.play.NoSql.<clinit>(NoSql.java:16)
at cz.muni.fi.cassandra.Playorm.UserPlayormDaoImplTest.setUp(UserPlayormDaoImplTest.java:34)
at junit.framework.TestCase.runBare(TestCase.java:132)
at junit.framework.TestResult$1.protect(TestResult.java:110)
at junit.framework.TestResult.runProtected(TestResult.java:128)
at junit.framework.TestResult.run(TestResult.java:113)
at junit.framework.TestCase.run(TestCase.java:124)
at junit.framework.TestSuite.runTest(TestSuite.java:243)
at junit.framework.TestSuite.run(TestSuite.java:238)
at org.junit.internal.runners.JUnit38ClassRunner.run(JUnit38ClassRunner.java:83)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: play.Plugin
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
... 30 more
```

Comment: Today, I check your code. The structure of your project is not like a Play framework project. Please note that the play plugin is only for Play framework and not to use otherwise. You can see how the plugin was used for Play framework 1.0.x in an example project given at https://github.com/deanhiller/playorm-server.

Answer (score 1):

Which version of play you are using? 
play.Plugin is part of play2.1.0 framework. Can you check if the jar "play_2.10.jar" located at play-2.1.0/repository/local/play/play_2.10/2.1.0/jars/play_2.10.jar is in your project's classpath.

Answer (score 0):

My fault, I didn't add play_2.10.jar from play-2.1.0/repository/local/play/play_2.10/2.1.0/jars/play_2.10.jar to my project's classpath before. I am using playframework 2.1.0 (downloaded from playframework website). I added that jar, but now I have similar problem with other class. Seems like there are more missing jars in classpath. Stacktrace:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/Function0
at play.api.Play.current(Play.scala)
at play.Play.application(Play.java:12)
at com.alvazan.play2.NoSqlForPlay2.em(NoSqlForPlay2.java:25)
at com.alvazan.play.NoSql.em(NoSql.java:60)
at cz.muni.fi.cassandra.Playorm.UserPlayormDaoImplTest.setUp(UserPlayormDaoImplTest.java:35)
at junit.framework.TestCase.runBare(TestCase.java:132)
at junit.framework.TestResult$1.protect(TestResult.java:110)
at junit.framework.TestResult.runProtected(TestResult.java:128)
at junit.framework.TestResult.run(TestResult.java:113)
at junit.framework.TestCase.run(TestCase.java:124)
at junit.framework.TestSuite.runTest(TestSuite.java:243)
at junit.framework.TestSuite.run(TestSuite.java:238)
at org.junit.internal.runners.JUnit38ClassRunner.run(JUnit38ClassRunner.java:83)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: scala.Function0
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
... 19 more
```

Comment: Yes. I believe this and all others should come by default in your play project if you are using Eclipse and do "play eclipse" from your project directory.